# Set WebView initial zoom level (start it so page fits)

Tags: react-native

I have a webview, and I set it's html like this:

```
<WebView source={{ html:body }} style={{ width:400; }} scalesPageToFit />
```

However on load, the page within is zoomed at 100% so its outside of the boundaries. Is it possible to start the zoom at a level so it fits perfectly inside the boundaries?

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiNeg.png

I want it to start zoomed so all content fits like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN3BT.png (i manually pinched to zoom out here)

I thought the `scalesPageToFit` prop would do this, but its not doing anything, whether true or false. Does anyone know what `scalesPageToFit` does?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scalesPageToFit` avoids your web page to outscale in the webView, so that its minimum zoom does not show empty spaces.
Since [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#scalespagetofit) version 0.52 a new prop `initialScale` is provided and seems to be exactly what you're looking for. Unfortunately it has never been added to the code: an issue is still open.

So, in order to achieve your objective, you have to use `nativeConfig` to override the native component behavior: what I mean is fully explained in these two examples:

1. [First](https://github.com/cbrevik/webview-native-config-example)
2. [Second](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/website/versioned_docs/version-0.5/custom-webview-android.md)

Comment: Thanks I think this is ocrrect! Until then I used meta properties to control zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar WebView with a header and style={{flex : 1}} achieves this for me.